# Who is the official registrar of the .com domain name?

Tags: domains, top-level-domains, domain-registrar

I know there are official registrars for some domains (especially 2-digit country domains), so are there registrars for all of them? For example, who is the **official** registrar for `.com`, `.net`, or `.org`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verisign is the *administrator* for [.com](http://www.verisigninc.com/en_US/products-and-services/domain-name-services/registry-services/com-domain-names/index.xhtml) and [.net](http://www.verisigninc.com/en_US/products-and-services/domain-name-services/registry-services/net-domain-names/index.xhtml), but doesn't directly provide registration services itself. There isn't any "official" registry for those TLDs, just [accredited registrars](http://www.verisigninc.com/en_US/products-and-services/domain-name-services/find-registrar/index.xhtml).

The [Public Interest Registry](http://www.pir.org/about) administers .org, and the situation is similar to the other two. While they do provide a domain search function, but once it's confirmed available, you're prompted to click a banner ad for a "featured" (randomized) registrar or visit their complete list in order to actually purchase it.